# How to bind resources string to Xaml in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

How do you bind resources string to Xaml  in Silverlight?

Comment: You misspelled Xaml, twice. Might wanna fix that.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this reference to the App.xaml

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then you need to add the string into the `<Application.Resources>` section

```
<sys:String x:Key="ResourceString">Resource String</clr:String>
```

Then all you need to do is refer to *{StaticResource ResourceString} 
for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ResourceString}"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since this was asked and answered, I just wanted to add an additional answer as the first one is not entirely correct. I think he's asking for resources, aka. text written in .resx files. It doesn't make sense at all to add individual strings into the StaticResources collection in the application.

I blogged recently on how to simplify the way you work with resources in Silverlight, enabling both automatic update when the culture changes and a dependency property which gives you simpler syntax.

http://sondreb.com/blog/post/Simplifying-Text-Resources-in-Silverlight.aspx